# Is there a way to view/use web developer tools by plugging an android phone into a Windows 11 PC?

Tags: javascript, android, google-pixel

I'm not a mobile app developer but I do develop an intranet which has an app which was created for us. The app uses web controls to display a mobile HTML interface within the intranet. Every now and then we'll see a bug which may be related to a javascript or HTML error. I'm wondering if there is some sort of emulator which will allow me to check for errors in the same way we do for Chrome/Edge etc. The process being to right-click, click on 'Inspect' and then look at what we need to look at (usually in the Elements, Network or Console tabs). I'm aware of emulators but not sure if any can provide this sort of connection. When I had a Mac I was able to do this with iPhone and Safari.

The specific issue is with the latest Pixel phone and a file upload button that won't work. I'd like to be able to check if there's a javascript error happening when the page loads and/or whether the click on the upload button is triggering an error.

We've tested on other Android phones but it seems to only be the latest Pixel that doesn't want to work.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: If the web site is loaded into a WebView inside an app remote debugging is by default disabled. For allowing remote debugging the app code needs to be changed.